# firefox vs phonegap geolocation accuracy

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

I've made simple application using javascript geolocation api and I have tested on my mobile phone with firefox browser. It was able to achieve 3-5 meters accuracy of gps position. Then I used build.phonegap.com to create an .apk. It works fine but I've notice that accuracy is less then in firefox max 10-15 meters. Is it possible to correct it?

Comment: For your PhoneGap app, have you added the Cordova geolocation plugin to your project?

Comment: I add in index.html    `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` and     `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"         source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />` in config.xml